# how to stop updating progress bar that showing on notification panel from background Service when on Destroy() of Service is Called

Tags: android, multithreading, service, background, notifications

What i am doing here that I have started one service from Activity.Once Service is started it's start another background thread from on start Command() from that its showing progress bar update using delayed Thread on Notification panel using Notification Manger but What issue is When i stop service from activity than on destroy() of service is called and i stop updating progress bar i.e  i have called this notification manager .cancel All() or  thread. current Thread().interrupt() from on Destroy() of Service but Progress bar is not stop updating on notification Panel still its updating. I have tried all possible solution but Thread is not stop or progress bar not stop to updating on notification panel its still showing so how to stop Progress bar on updating on notification panel what i have done so far as following please help me to resolve the issue.Thanks.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button start, stop;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start);
        stop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stop);


        start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {


                startService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, NotificationService.class));
            }
        });

        stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {


                stopService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, NotificationService.class));


            }
        });


    }

 }
```

NotificationService.java

```
public class NotificationService extends Service {

    private Thread thread;
    private NotificationManager mNotifyManager;
    private Builder mBuilder;


    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mNotifyManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(getApplicationContext().NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(NotificationService.this);


        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "oncreate of service called", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onStart of service called", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        mBuilder.setContentTitle("Download")
                .setContentText("Download in progress")
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);


        mBuilder.setProgress(100, 0, false);
        mNotifyManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());


        updateService();

        return START_NOT_STICKY;


    }

    private void updateService() {

        thread = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {


                for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i += 5) {
                    // Sets the progress indicator completion percentage

                    try {


                        mBuilder.setProgress(100, i, false);
                        mNotifyManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());

                        // Sleep for 5 seconds
                        Thread.sleep(2 * 1000);

                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        Log.d("TAG", "sleep failure");
                    }


                }


                mBuilder.setContentText("Download complete");
                // Removes the progress bar
                mBuilder.setProgress(0, 0, false);
                mNotifyManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());


            }
        };

        thread.start();


    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();


        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "service Destroyed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        //  mNotifyManager.cancelAll();
        //mNotifyManager.cancel(0);
        thread.currentThread().interrupt();

        // mNotifyManager.cancel(0);

        // mNotifyManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thread.interrupt() does not interrupt the thread immediately. It only update interrupt status of thread. If your thread contains method which poll the interrupt status (i.e. sleep ) only then the thread will be interrupted otherwise the thread simply complete the execution and interrupt status will be ignored.

So, In your case you do following way:

```
private class MyWorkerThread extends Thread {

    public MyWorkerThread(String name) {
        super(name);
    }

    private boolean isStopThread = false;

    public void setStopThread(boolean isStopThread) {
        this.isStopThread = isStopThread;
    }


    @Override
    public void run() {
        super.run();

        for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i += 5) {
            // Sets the progress indicator completion percentage

            try {

                if (mWorkerThread.isStopThread) {
                    Log.d("Thread", "thread is interrupted , so breaking loop !");
                    mWorkerThread.interrupt();
                    mWorkerThread = null;
                    break;
                }

                mBuilder.setProgress(100, i, false);
                mNotifyManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());

                // Sleep for 5 seconds
                Thread.sleep(2 * 1000);

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Log.d("TAG", "sleep failure");
            }


        }


        mBuilder.setContentText("Download complete");
        // Removes the progress bar
        mBuilder.setProgress(0, 0, false);
        mNotifyManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());

    }
}
```

**UpdateService method:**

```
private void updateService() {

        mWorkerThread = new MyWorkerThread("MyWorkerThread");
        mWorkerThread.start();

    }
```

**OnDestroy() method**

```
@Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();


        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "service Destroyed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        //  mNotifyManager.cancelAll();
        //mNotifyManager.cancel(0);
        //Setting flag for stop thread
        mWorkerThread.setStopThread(true);


        // mNotifyManager.cancel(0);

        // mNotifyManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());


    }
```

Hope it help you !

Comment: thanks bro.for your answer. i know this the flag true or false and break in loop do a trick.but how to stop upadating progress bar on notification panel using mNotifyManager.cancelAll() method available on Notificationmanager using these method it's does not stop updating progressbar or only using trick you show me is possible

Comment: @Viral mNotifyManager.cancellAll() is working perfectly and stop updating once.but your thread is running so it generate again notification.

Comment: @Viral I checked your code, you can just add a bool variable inside loop if notification is cancel then break the loop

Comment: mNotifyManger.cancelAll() clear notification if any showing. After clearing this line mNotifyManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build()); generate again with updated progress value.

Comment: Thanks for your great help!!

Comment: So u means I have to manually stop or interrupted the thread for updating progress bar on notification panel.

Comment: yes  of course, thread will not auto stop until complete the execution of run() method or some one interrupt it.

Comment: I have put thread.interrupt on on destroy() method but still thread is not stopped I think only break is do a job from loop to stop thread.

Comment: you must have to break the loop .

Comment: read this https://praveer09.github.io/technology/2015/12/06/understanding-thread-interruption-in-java/